# Stuffing an anonymous type in ViewBag causing model binder issues

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? :-)

I have this simple query:

```
 var sample = from training in _db.Trainings
              where training.InstructorID == 10
              select new { Something = training.Instructor.UserName };
```

And I pass this to ViewBag.

```
ViewBag.Sample = sample;
```

Then I want to access it in my view like this:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Sample) {
    @item.Something
}
```

And I get error message 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Something'. If I put there just `@item`, I get result `{ Something = SomeUserName }`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This cannot be done. ViewBag is dynamic and the problem is that the anonymous type is generated as internal. I would recommend you using a view model:

```
public class Instructor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var mdoel = from training in _db.Trainings
                 where training.InstructorID == 10
                 select new Instructor { 
                     Name = training.Instructor.UserName 
                 };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Instructor>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Sample) {
    @item.Something
}
```

Comment: +1 - Notice how he's selecting a `new Instructor` a concrete type - not an anonymous type. That way he can access the information within the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send in ViewData For example and don't want to send in model 
you could use the same could as in the upper answer 
and in the Controller

```
enter code here


ViewData[Instractor] = from training in _db.Trainings
                 where training.InstructorID == 10
                 select new Instructor { 
                     Name = training.Instructor.UserName 
                 };
```

and in the view you need to cast this to

```
`IEnumerable<Instructor>`
```

but to do this you should use

```
@model IEnumerable<Instructor>
```

Then  you could do something like this

```
IEnumerable<instructors> Instructors =(IEnumerable<Instructor>)ViewData[Instractor];
```

then go with foreach

```
@foreach (var item in Instructors ) {
    @item.Something
}
```