# MVC - ViewModel

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel

I need to create a linq statement that combines 2 tables and send that to the view.

Do I need to create a ViewModel for this.

Say the output will be the following

Table1.Vendor Table1.VendorName Table2.Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what your result type is.

If you return <s>a dynamic object</s> an anonymous type then you can't put that into the ViewBag directly (see: [Stuffing an anonymous type in ViewBag causing model binder issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649536/entity-framework-select-new)). But if you're returning something that's strongly typed, you can just put that straight into the ViewBag and bypass having a model.

That said, I'd always lean towards having a strongly typed model!

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Should use  View-model because if u want to send more than one table you may
use ViewBag or something equivalent viewdata[]  that's wrong etc..
Because ViewBag for example is  dynamic type it can't be sent to view with 2 table 
For example if you do something like this

```
 ViewBag.Workers=db.Workers.Join(idb.AspNetUsers, e => e.UserID, i => i.Id, (e, i) => new { UserName = i.UserName, SBIN = e.SBIN, }).ToList();
```

You will Get error 500 when you use this viewbag in your View

```
<span>@ViewBag.Workers.Anything</span>
```

Even in this example you should use for-each you still get error becausethe ViewBag is internal
So You could use something like that in the controller for this issue

```
    var Workers=db.Workers.Join(idb.AspNetUsers, e => e.UserID, i => i.Id, (e, i) => new WorkerViewCardModelcs{ UserName = i.UserName, SBIN = e.SBIN, }).ToList();
return PartialView("_WorkerCard", Workers);
```

and Don't for get to use @model in the View or Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<FinalProject.ViewModels.WorkerViewCardModelcs>


@foreach (var item in Model)
                {
What ever logic you wish 
}
```