# ViewBag is returning NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I have retrived a data list from database. The datalist works fine in controller class and does indeed have values in it but when I bind it with `ViewBag.List` and try to render it in view it give `NullReferenceException`. I have no idea why would it gives that exception. 
**ControllerClass**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var SomeList = Database.somelamdaexp.ToList();
    ViewBag.List = SomeList;
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.List)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.Field1<td>
        <td>@item.Field2</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Please put your controller code and what you have tried

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: I would use another name for the list, like: ViewBag.MyList, List is a type.

Comment: Better avoid `ViewBag` if possible and pass the list as/with a model to the view.

Comment: @UweKeim Yes turns out i was selecting datalist with some anonymous type in my lamdaexp and they are internal cannot be used in view. I created a modeview class and now it works. Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing an Anonymous Object in ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8980045/11683)

Answer (score 1):

Your the usage of `ViewBag` is correct, I cannot reproduce the problem, [see this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YBuXsn)

The problem could be because `Field1` or `Field2` does not exist in your model, or the exception is thrown somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @GSerg My bad i should have mentioned i have anonymous types in my lamda expression.Thanks for your time.