# Access data from Viewbag Objects which has multiple objects

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, data-binding

In Controller i have a viewbag which is defined as

```cs
var aut = from a in db.Model
            where a.UniqueReqID == vvid
            join b in db.Model2 on a.DeptID equals b.DepartmentID
            select new { a, b };
ViewBag.at = aut;
```

In View I want to access the fields extracted. like

```cs
foreach (var item in ViewBag.at)
{
    int i = 0;
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="DeptID" id="DeptID" value=@item.a.DepartmentName />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="CodeEntered" id="CodeEntered" @i placeholder="Enter Verification Code Received" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    i++;
}
```

At Runtime I am getting an error "'object' does not contain a definition for 'a'"
How can I access all the variables inside viewbag

Comment: You have to move ```int i = 0;````outside of _foreach_. In the current case, I will be reset every time to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The view bag container is basically a dictionary where the values are objects. Thus in the view you have to cast the value to an a concrete class. You are using anonymous so this make it difficult to do. See [Storing an Anonymous Object in ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8980045/5437903).

If you really want to use the view bag I would recommend creating a class and storing that in the viewbag.

But I would strongly recommend using a model instead.