# How to show grouped data in ASP.NET MVC razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have this code in my controller:

```
var taxes = db.invoiceTaxes
    .Where(c => c.invoiceId == invoice.invoiceId)
    .GroupBy(row => new { row.TaxId, row.tax, row.percent, row.type })
    .Select(group => new { tax = group.Key.tax, percent = group.Key.percent, sum = group.Sum(s => s.sum), type = group.Key.type });

ViewBag.taxes = taxes.ToList();
```

If I have this in my view

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.taxes)
{
    @item
}
```

I get

> { tax = Facturacion.Models.Tax, percent = 16, sum = 31.36, type = False }

But when I have

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.taxes)
{
    @item.percent
}
```

I get

> Object does not contain a definition for percent

How can I show the fields my query returns? (In this case, the value "16")

invoiceTaxes is not my model, it's Invoice

Comment: please edit your code to reflect the model name, as indicated in your comment below. and close the question as this is not a problem anymore (??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *could* (trivial sample, modify and improve as necessary):

```
//Some dummy class to mock some data to play with
//You don't need this..I just need some data to play with for the sample
public class DummyData
{
    public string InstructorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

In `Controller`:

```
public ActionResult DoDynamic()
{
    //Some data to use only for this sample (you already have some data to query, so you don't need this)
    var data = new List<DummyData>
    {
        new DummyData {Name = "Foo is my name", InstructorId = "Foo 1", Invoice = 1},
        new DummyData {Name = "Bar is my name", InstructorId = "Bar 1", Invoice = 2},
        new DummyData {Name = "Hello is my name", InstructorId = "Foo 2", Invoice = 1},
    };

    var query = data.Where(o => o.Invoice == 1).GroupBy(row => new { row.InstructorId }).Select(group => new { name = group.Key.InstructorId }).ToList();

    //Yeah, we can do dynamic :)
    dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
    foo.bar = "Hello from dynamic object";
    if (query.Any())
    {
        var result = "";
        query.ForEach(i => result += i.name + "<br />");
        foo.dyn = result;
    }

    //Lets use ViewBag
    ViewBag.SomeObject = foo;

    //And let's use model too...
    return View(foo);
}
```

Now for the `View`:

```
@model dynamic

<h2>DoDynamic</h2>

<p>View Bag: </p>
<ul>
    <li>@ViewBag.SomeObject.bar</li>
    <li>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SomeObject.dyn)</li>
</ul>

<p>From dynamic model: </p>
<ul>
    <li>@Model.bar</li>
    <li>@Html.Raw(Model.dyn)</li>
</ul>
```

Result:

[image: Rendered view]

Hope this gets you going...

Answer (score 1):

At controller you create anonymous type. Problem is that all properties of anonymous type created with `internal` accessor. So you can't use it on View.

For more detailed info you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649536/stuffing-an-anonymous-type-in-viewbag-causing-model-binder-issues).

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing the controler code as below

```
var taxes = db.invoiceTaxes
    .Where(c => c.invoiceId == invoice.invoiceId)
    .GroupBy(row => new { row.TaxId, row.tax, row.percent, row.type })
    .Select(group => new { tax = group.Key.tax, percent = group.Key.percent, sum = group.Sum(s => s.sum), type = group.Key.type });

return View(taxes.ToList()); // Changed here from Viewbag to View(model)
```

In view

```
@model IEnumerable<Facturacion.Models.Tax>
//Some code here to define UI etc
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.percent)
    </td>

}
```

Comment: The problem is "invoiceTax" is not the model, the model's name is "Invoice"

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new viewmodel to hold the values (if you don't have one already).

then use

```
 .Select(group => new InvoiceTaxViewModel { 
    tax = group.Key.tax, 
    percent = group.Key.percent, 
    sum = group.Sum(s => s.sum), 
    type = group.Key.type });
```

Then in your view you should cast the ViewBag object back to a `List<Of Model>`

```
@foreach (var item in (List<InvoiceTaxViewModel>)ViewBag.taxes)
{
    @item.percent
}
```

I would probably create a new object in the view just before this

```
@{
    var invoiceTaxList = ViewBag.taxes as List<InvoiceTaxViewModel>;
}

@foreach (var item in invoiceTaxList)
{
    @item.percent
}
```